# Java crypt file using XOR

Tags: java, android, security, encryption, xor

I'm trying to find a very efficient way to encrypt files. 
One way that I think is very efficient ( CPU-wise, not security-level wise ), is doing a XOR during writing and another xor at reading ( with a 4-bytes key for example ).

The way I want to do it is by creating my own Decorator of InputStream and OutputStream. Does anyone know a better method/most efficient than that ?

Comment: Note that a XOR cipher isn't really cryptographically strong or secure. By itself, using a constant repeating key, a simple XOR cipher can trivially be broken using frequency analysis.

Comment: That's right and this level of security is enough for my use case.

Comment: But are you sure that CTR mode is not fast enough? Because if you check the page on CTR on wikipedia you will quickly see that you can calculate key stream in advance, and use XOR-ing of the created key stream with the cipher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The way I want to do it is by creating my own Decorator of InputStream
>   and OutputStream. Does anyone know a better method/most efficient than
>   that

Create subclasses of FilterInputStream and FilterOutputStream.

Comment: And if you do, do implement the write methods that take a byte array, not just the one that takes a single byte. Make sure the output if buffered somewhere.

Comment: hi, could you give a an example for that? As I don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

An XOR cypher is an example of a Stream Cypher.  An obsolete, but easy to program, example is RC4.  For more modern, but not so easy, examples have a look at the cyphers in the [eSTREAM](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/) portfolio: HC-128, Rabbit, Salsa 20/12 and SOSEMANUK.

Alternatively, a Block Cypher, such as AES, used in CTR Mode is equivalent to a Stream Cypher.

If you do not need very strong security then try RC4.  Otherwise, AES in CTR Mode is probably the easiest, given its universal availability.

Comment: I believe that the correct spelling of 'cypher', in this context, is 'cipher'. 'Cypher' refers to a completely different meaning.

Comment: @Delan_Azabani: It may be a difference between UK and US English.  I am British so I tend to use 'cypher', though 'cipher' is also acceptable.

Comment: @Delan Dictionaries say cypher and cipher are equivalents, though you've made a good point - in cryptography the word "cipher" is used.